# Lua dissector causing Wireshark to consume all available memory

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

My protocol is very chatty and the payloads are rather large.  I am attempting to have my Lua dissector utilize Wireshark's TCP reassembly, and then parse the bytes.  My dissector works well if I have only a few packets within a .pcap file - the reassembly is working, and the bytes are as expected once the last PDU is reached. The more frames there are, the faster (and larger) the memory consumption of Wireshark becomes (until it runs out and bails on me).  However, it doesn't take many frames to reach that point.  Your assistance is appreciated.

```
SOMETHING_TCP_PORT = 30003
SOMETHING = Proto("SOMETHING","SOMETHING")

function SOMETHING.init()
end

function SOMETHING.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
if buffer:len() > 3 then
if string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "0401F0CE" then
    tvbLength = 20728
elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "0501F0CE" then
    tvbLength = 12024
elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "2201F0CE" then
    tvbLength = 7028
elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "2B01F0CE" then
    tvbLength = 7028
else
    tvbLength = buffer:len()
end
end

pinfo.cols.info = "SOMETHING "
pinfo.cols.protocol = "SOMETHING"

local n = pinfo.desegment_offset or 0
while true do
local nextPDU = n + tvbLength

if nextPDU > buffer:len() then
    pinfo.desegment_len = nextPDU - buffer:len()
    pinfo.desegment_offset = n
    return
end

if string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2201F0CE" or string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2B01F0CE" then
    if string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2201F0CE" then
        pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Message ")

        subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

        subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "Found - " .. string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))))
        n = n + 4
    elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2B01F0CE" then
        pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Other Message ")

        subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

        subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "Found - " .. string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))))
        n = n + 4
    else
        return
    end

    subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size = " .. buffer(n, 4):le_uint() .. " bytes")
    if buffer(n, 4):le_uint() ~= 7028 then
        subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size is incorrect!")
    end
    n = n + 4

    -- DECODE HERE

    n = nextPDU
    if nextPDU == buffer:len() then
        return
    end
end

if string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "0401F0CE" then
    pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Message ")

    subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

    subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "Found - " .. string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))))
    n = n + 4

    subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size = " .. buffer(n, 4):le_uint() .. " bytes")
    if buffer(n, 4):le_uint() ~= 20728 then
        subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size is incorrect!")
    end
    n = n + 4

    -- DECODE HERE

    n = nextPDU
    if nextPDU == buffer:len() then
        return
    end
end

if string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "0501F0CE" then
    pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Message ")

    subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

    subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "Found - " .. string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))))
    n = n + 4

    subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size = " .. buffer(n, 4):le_uint() .. " bytes")
    if buffer(n, 4):le_uint() ~= 12024 then
        subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size is incorrect!")
    end
    n = n + 4

    -- DECODE HERE

    n = nextPDU
    if nextPDU == buffer:len() then
        return
    end
end
end
end

tcp_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")

tcp_table:add(SOMETHING_TCP_PORT,SOMETHING)
```

Comment: You seem to be creating too many temporary strings. But that alone should not exhaust memory.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm desperate, so I'll see if getting rid of them helps.

Comment: `string.upper(tostring(buffer(0,4)` and `string.upper(tostring(buffer(n,4)` seem natural candidates for saving in a local variable. The code will be easier to read as well...

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's happening is wireshark is getting stuck in your while-loop, and never returning from it.  This can happen because in certain cases your code will never have `nextPDU` be greater than `buffer:len()`.  For example, if your dissector sees a TCP segment that has the first 4 bytes **not** match one of the hex strings you expect to see, then it will set `tvbLength = buffer:len()`, enter the while-loop with the variable `n` equal to `0`, and thus have a `nextPDU` equal to `buffer:len()`... but that's *equal-to*, not *greater-than*, so the while loop won't return... **ever**.  And since the if-then statements within the while loop allocate memory (by creating multiple `TvbRange`s), the memory usage will keep growing and growing.

So you're going to have to change your code logic to prevent being stuck in that while-loop forever.  Like for example verify the `nextPDU` value changes on each loop, or something.

---

Also, your code is fairly inefficient - it creates a bunch of `TvbRange` objects and Lua strings multiple times instead of once.

For example, at the top of the dissector function:

```
if buffer:len() > 3 then
    if string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "0401F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 20728
    elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "0501F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 12024
    elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "2201F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 7028
    elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4))) == "2B01F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 7028
    else
        tvbLength = buffer:len()
    end
end
```

There are three things in that if-then block that cause memory to be allocated:

1. `buffer(0,4)` creates a `TvbRange` object in C-code and Lua.
2. `tostring()` of the `TvbRange` creates a string in Lua.
3. `string.upper()` creates another string in Lua.

You call those three things up to four times in the above if-then block, depending on whether the `elseif` clauses get executed.  For numbers 2 and 3 above, they will only create one string each in Lua for all four if/elseif clauses because they result in the same string and Lua internally only stores one copy of a given string; but still it's extra processing that isn't necessary.  Instead, you should do this:

```
if buffer:len() > 3 then
    local msgType = string.upper(tostring(buffer(0, 4)))
    if msgType == "0401F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 20728
    elseif msgType == "0501F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 12024
    elseif msgType == "2201F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 7028
    elseif msgType == "2B01F0CE" then
        tvbLength = 7028
    else
        tvbLength = buffer:len()
    end
end
```

That both reduces the memory allocated, and improves performance.

By the way, what if `buffer:len()` is **not** greater than 3?  Then `tvbLength` isn't set to anything.

---

Next you have this:

```
    if string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2201F0CE" or string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2B01F0CE" then
        if string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2201F0CE" then
            pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Message ")

            subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

            subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "Found - " .. string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))))
            n = n + 4
        elseif string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))) == "2B01F0CE" then
            pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Other Message ")

            subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

            subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "Found - " .. string.upper(tostring(buffer(n, 4))))
            n = n + 4
        else
            return
        end

        subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size = " .. buffer(n, 4):le_uint() .. " bytes")
        if buffer(n, 4):le_uint() ~= 7028 then
            subtree:add(buffer(n, 4), "  Message size is incorrect!")
        end
        n = n + 4

        -- DECODE HERE

        n = nextPDU
        if nextPDU == buffer:len() then
            return
        end
    end
```

Again, you're creating multiple `TvbRange` objects and strings for them and so on, even though they're identical.  So instead do this:

```
    local msgTypeBuf = buffer(n, 4)
    local msgType = string.upper(tostring(msgTypeBuf))
    if msgType == "2201F0CE" or msgType == "2B01F0CE" then
        if msgType == "2201F0CE" then
            pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Message ")

            subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

            subtree:add(msgTypeBuf, "Found - " .. msgType)
            n = n + 4
        elseif msgType == "2B01F0CE" then
            pinfo.cols.info:append("- Some Other Message ")

            subtree = tree:add(SOMETHING, buffer(), "SOMETHING - Some Message")

            subtree:add(msgTypeBuf, "Found - " .. msgType)
            n = n + 4
        else
            return
        end

        local msgLengthBuf = buffer(n, 4)
        local msgLength = msgLengthBuf:le_uint()
        subtree:add(msgLengthBuf, "  Message size = " .. msgLength .. " bytes")
        if msgLength ~= 7028 then
            subtree:add(msgLengthBuf, "  Message size is incorrect!")
        end
        n = n + 4

        -- DECODE HERE

        n = nextPDU
        if nextPDU == buflen then
            return
        end
    end
```

And similarly in the later if-then statements.